# pxssh raspberry pi password refused

Tags: python, ssh, raspberry-pi

I try to connect in ssh with pxssh in python, I have the following error **password refused**.

```
import pexpect
from pexpect import pxssh

try:
    ssh = pxssh.pxssh()
    ssh.login('192.168.1.48', 'pi', 'raspberry')
    ssh.logout()
except Exception as e:
    print("ssh failed")
    print(e)
```

But if I login ssh normally, I do not have the error.

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.48
pi@192.168.1.54's password:raspberry
```